# Run an exe on a remote pc

Tags: sql-server, web-services, wcf, cruisecontrol.net, remote-server

I'm just after some general advice.

We have red gate install with sqlcompare.exe on server 1. From my build server (server 2) I want to run sqlcompare.exe with some command line options.

What's the best way to do this? Could I create a WCF service hosted on server1 in iis and call the exe that way. The exe I want to run may take a few minutes to complete and I want to return the output back to server1 including errors.

p.s. I don't have the option to install the exe on service "

Thanks

Comment: Which build tool are you using? And it would help to understand the problem are you ultimately trying to solve by running sqlcompare.exe.

Comment: I'm using sql compare to synchronised two databases.

Comment: What build tool are you using to drive the process? Jenkins, TeamCity, TFS Build? CruiseControl?

Comment: Cruise control with nant scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

Server 1 must be a [build agent for Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/distributed/).

1) You check sqlcompare.exe (and the necessary dlls) into version control and execute this as part of your NAnt build script. You reference sqlcompare.exe in terms of the relative path from your check out folder.

2) You install sqlcompare.exe on your build agent (which you seem to have done already), and execute this as part of your NAnt build script. You reference sqlcompare.exe in terms of its absolute path. If you later have multiple build agents, you need to make sure that sqlcompare.exe is installed in the same path.